# Library using different ndk.abiFilters than main app but it compiles for both

Tags: android, android-ndk

Is it possible to compile main app with

```
ndk { abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a" }
```

And Library module with

```
ndk { abiFilters "arm64-v8a"}
```

So that Library .so files only get compiled for arm64-v8a?
I have some other libraries in another module with "armeabi-v7a" so for each cpu only that libraries that it needs.

Library .gradle is always ignored and app compiles then Library modules for arm64-v8a and also armeabi-v7a which I don't need and they take 20mb of size

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I kinda solved this.

What I did is excluded all files directly in build.gradle

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude '/lib/armeabi-v7a/first.so'
    exclude '/lib/armeabi-v7a/second.so'
    ...
}
```

And now it removes this files after building